# Laravel display html in Blade

Tags: php, laravel

How do I escape out of blade syntax to show html in an if data exists statement?

```
{{ $manager->first_name or '<a href="/add">add</a>' }}
```

Will just show the html tags as well. All I saw in the docs was escap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That kind of logic is not the best way to do things... In your view, You should do the following

```
@if (null !== $manager->first_name)
    {{ $manager->first_name }}
@else
    <a href="/add">add</a>
@endif
```

There may be some changes needed to the code for the if/else statement to validate correctly, but this is the basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this `{!! $manager->first_name or '<a href="/add">add</a>' !!}`

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to celia's answer; you should still escape the data:

`{!! isset($manager->first_name) ? e($manager->first_name) : '<a href="/add">add</a>' !!}`